# Displaying Recyclerview on service

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have no idea how to do it, i'm trying to display the recyclerview from service since the service supposed to inflate the layout alongside the recyclerview. Currently, it only inflates the layout, blank and the recyclerview is missing. BTW this layout supposed to display within the lockscreen (Inflate on top of it). Or do you have any methods to display a recyclerview on lockscreen?

```
public class LockScreenMemontumService extends Service {

private LinearLayout linearLayout;
private WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams;
private WindowManager windowManager;
FloatingActionButton btnCancel;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Context ctx;
List<Memo> data = new ArrayList<>();
List<Memo> arrayMemo;
View view;
LayoutInflater li;
ListAdapter listAdapter;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // Not used
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(screenReceiver, intentFilter);
    li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    windowManager = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE));
    layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION, //hiding the home screen button
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
}


private void init(Context ctx) {
    linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    windowManager.addView(linearLayout, layoutParams);
    view = li.inflate(R.layout.lockscreen_layout, linearLayout);
    this.ctx = ctx;
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.memorecyclerView);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(ctx));
    try {
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(ctx,data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }catch (Exception x) {x.printStackTrace();}

    btnCancel = view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelScreen);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(listener);

}

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){

            case R.id.btnCancelScreen:
                windowManager.removeView(linearLayout);
                linearLayout = null;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(screenReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}

BroadcastReceiver screenReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF) && linearLayout == null) {
            init(context);

        }
    }
};}
```

Here's my Listadapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<Memo> data;
Context context;
ListInterface listInterface = null;
boolean state = true;

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Memo> data) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    listInterface = (ListInterface)context;
}

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Memo> data, boolean state) {
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
    listInterface = (ListInterface)context;
    this.state = state;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Memo memo = data.get(position);
    if(state==true) {
        Glide.with(context).load(memo.getImg()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_black_24dp).into(holder.imgThumb);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(memo.getTitle());
        holder.txtContents.setText(memo.getMemo());
        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        holder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    listInterface.goDetail(memo.getId());
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } else if(state==false) {
        Glide.with(context).load(memo.getImg()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_black_24dp).into(holder.imgThumb);
        holder.txtTitle.setText(memo.getTitle());
        holder.txtContents.setText(memo.getMemo());
        holder.mCheckBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.mCheckBox.setClickable(false);

        holder.card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(holder.mCheckBox.isChecked()) {
                    holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                    ListFragment.deleteList.remove(ListFragment.deleteList.indexOf(memo.getId()));
                    Log.w("id", String.valueOf(memo.getId()));
                } else {
                    holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                    ListFragment.deleteList.add(memo.getId());
                    Log.w("id", String.valueOf(memo.getId()));
                }
                for(int item:ListFragment.deleteList) {
                    Log.w("list", String.valueOf(item));
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    CheckBox mCheckBox;
    ImageView imgThumb;
    TextView txtTitle, txtContents;
    CardView card;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        card = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        imgThumb = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        txtTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        txtContents = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
    }
}}
```

The List Interface

```
public interface ListInterface {
public void goDetail();
public void goDetail(long position) throws SQLException;
public void delete(int position) throws SQLException;}
```

And here's the error

```
04-16 01:52:20.018 21520-21520/com.example.jcgut.notethunder W/System.err: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.jcgut.notethunder.LockScreenMemontumService cannot be cast to com.example.jcgut.notethunder.interfaces.ListInterface
    at com.example.jcgut.notethunder.ListAdapter.<init>(ListAdapter.java:31)
    at com.example.jcgut.notethunder.LockScreenMemontumService.init(LockScreenMemontumService.java:98)
    at com.example.jcgut.notethunder.LockScreenMemontumService.access$200(LockScreenMemontumService.java:52)
    at com.example.jcgut.notethunder.LockScreenMemontumService$2.onReceive(LockScreenMemontumService.java:134)
    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:997)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Could you paste the logcat in case you are getting any errors?

Comment: i posted the error,

Answer (score 0):

This is how you show an UI component from service.

```
   li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                //WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,// | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        myview = li.inflate(R.layout.traslucent, null);     

        wm.addView(myview, params);
```

**Note :**

> I don't recommended this way of showing UI. Instead you can start an
>   activity with your needy UI. There you will have full control on UI
>   and you will easily able to manipulate things.

Answer (score -1):

In onCreate method you should first initialise the recyclerview. Else it will show "No adapter attached; skipping layout"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).